# Get td by title with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

as topic says, how do I get a td in a table by it's title? I then want to hide it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the `title` attribute, or by the `<table>`'s `<caption>`, or something else? Any example?

Comment: did you mean  $("td[title='mytitle']") ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$('td[title=Herbert]').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("td[title='mytitle']")....
```

look at this link :

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 2):

Something like ...

```
$('table[title="the title"]').hide();
```

or if using the caption ...

```
$('table[caption="the caption"]').hide();
```

Bearing in mind the following:

> If you wish to use any of the
>   meta-characters
>   (#;&,.+*~':"!^$=>|/ ) as a literal
>   part of a name, you must escape the
>   character with two backslashes: \\.
>   For example, if you have an an input
>   with name="names[]", you can use the
>   selector $("input[name=names\\[\\]]").

As per [Selectors - JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: sorry I misread as 'table by title', my jquery should read as `$('td[title="the title"]').hide();` so not to confuse anybody.

Answer (score 0):

By title as attribute: `td[title="table title"]`

By title as content: `td:contains(table title)`

Please be more explicit.